# Remove words from list containing certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a long list of words that I'm trying to go through and if the word contains a specific character remove it. However, the solution I thought would work doesn't and doesn't remove any words

```
l3 = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']


firstcheck = ['poach', 'omnificent', 'aminoxylol', 'teetotaller', 'kyathos', 'toxaemic', 'herohead', 'desole', 'nincompoophood', 'dinamode']

validwords = []

for i in l3:
    for x in firstchect:
        if i not in x:
            validwords.append(x)
            continue
        else:
            break
```

If a word from firstcheck has a character from l3 I want it removed or not added to this other list. I tried it both ways. Can anyone offer insight on what could be going wrong? I'm pretty sure I could use some list comprehension but I'm not very good at that.

Comment: On a side note, that `continue` is no good

Comment: The spelling of `firstcheck` in 'for x in firstchet` is wrong. Also, @Henry Prince, you can see my answer below. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer makes use of `np.sum` which means importing a huge numerical library to perform a simple task that the Python kernel can easily do by itself:

```
validwords = [w for w in firstcheck if all(c not in w for c in l3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
[w for w in firstcheck if np.sum([c in w for c in l3])==0]
```

It seems all the words contain at least 1 char from l3 and the output of above is an empty list.

If firstcheck is defined as below:

```
firstcheck = ['a', 'z', 'poach', 'omnificent']
```

The code should output:

```
['a', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, there was some mistake in code, rest was fine:

```
l3 = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']


firstcheck = ['aza', 'ca', 'poach', 'omnificent', 'aminoxylol', 'teetotaller', 'kyathos', 'toxaemic', 'herohead', 'desole', 'nincompoophood', 'dinamode']

validwords = []
flag=1
for x in firstcheck:
    for i in l3:
        if i not in x:
            flag=1
        else:
            flag=0  
            break
    if(flag==1):
        validwords.append(x)   

print(validwords)
```

So, here the first mistake was, the `for loops`, we need to iterate through words first then, through l3, to avoid the readdition of elements.

Next, firstcheck spelling was wrong in 'for x in firstcheck` due to which error was there.

Also, I added a flag, such that if flag value is 1 it will add the element in validwords.
To, check I added new elements as `'aza' and 'ca'`, due to which, now it shows correct o/p as 'aza' and 'ca'.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid all loops etc, you can use `re` directly.

```py
import re
l3 = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
firstcheck = ['azz', 'poach', 'omnificent', 'aminoxylol', 'teetotaller', 'kyathos', 'toxaemic', 'herohead', 'desole', 'nincompoophood', 'dinamode']

# Create a regex string to remove.
strings_to_remove = "[{}]".format("".join(l3))
validwords = [x for x in firstcheck if re.sub(strings_to_remove, '', x) == x]
print(validwords)
```

Output:

```
['azz']
```